# What should be size of map if different objects(say 3) have same hash code, and as a result, present in same bucket?

Tags: dictionary, hashmap, hashcode

What should be size of map if different objects(say 3)  have same hash code, and as a result, present in same bucket?

Comment: can we know *why* or what is this needed for?

Answer (score 0):

The resulting size of the hash table depends on what [collision resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) scheme we are using.

In the simplest case, we are using something like **separate chaining (with linked lists)**.

In this case, we will have an array of N buckets and each bucket contains a reference to a linked list.

If we proceed to insert 3 items into the hash table, all of which share the *same* hash code, then the single target linked list would grow to length 3.

Thus, at a high level, we need at least N "units" of space to store bucket references *plus* 3 "units" of space to store the elements of the (occupied) linked list.

The exact size of these "units", depends on implementation details, such as word size (32-bit vs. 64-bit) and the exact definition of the linked list (singly- vs. doubly-linked list).

Assuming that we use singly-linked lists (for each bucket) on a 32-bit machine, the total size would be (approximately) `32 * N + (32 + x) * 3`, where `x` refers to the size of the data type we are storing (e.g. ints, doubles, string, etc.)

If you would like to learn more, I would suggest googling "hash table collision" for more info.